# NSPredicate for exact match

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

```
 NSArray *arrData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"cloud,country,plant",
                    @"country,cloud,plant",
                    @"country,plant,cloud",
                    @"clouds,country,plant"
                    ,@"country,clouds,plant",
                    nil];
```

From above NSArray, I want objects which having a word "cloud"

I tried below code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self beginswith %@ OR self contains[CD] %@)",@"cloud",@",cloud"];
NSArray *arrResult = [arrData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But it's giving all 5 objects in arrResult. But I need only 3 (0,1,2) objects.

Comment: every object in array is comma seperated value ?

Comment: You could use a `NSRegularExpression` with a `MATCHES` predicate, and search for something like cloud at the end of the string, or cloud followed by a non-letter character.

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@+\\W", @"cloud"];` ?

Comment: @Larme: Getting crash 'Unable to parse the format string "SELF MATCHES[cd] %@+\W"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(NSString* string, NSDictionary* options){

    NSArray* array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    return [array containsObject:@"cloud"];

}];
```

Comment: Thanks @AndreyChernukha

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code,**

It will work,

```
 NSPredicate *hsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
        NSArray *sepretArray =[((NSString*)evaluatedObject) componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSPredicate *subPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@",@"cloud"];
        return  ([sepretArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:subPredicate].count > 0);

    }];
    NSArray *arrResult = [arrData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:hsPredicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

This one do the trick.But i don't know whether it is the efficient way of doing this.

```
 NSArray *arrData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"cloud,country,plant",
                    @"country,cloud,plant",
                    @"country,plant,cloud",
                    @"clouds,country,plant"
                    ,@"country,clouds,plant",
                    nil];

NSMutableArray *resArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSString *tempString in arrData)
{
    NSArray *cache = [tempString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if([cache containsObject:@"cloud"])
      {
        [resArray addObject:tempString];
      }
}
```