# NSPredicate with Regular Expression weirdness

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I am trying to find a match in an nested array if any string in an array is contained in a given sentence.

Here is my Array

```
NSArray *menuItems = @[
                  @[@"beverage", @"drink", @"smoothie", @"coffee", @"juice", @"shakes", @"tea", @"beer"],
                  @[@"breakfast", @"egg", @"omelet", @"bagel", @"yogurt", @"pancake", @"cereal", @"waffle", @"oatmeal", @"parfait", @"yoghurt", @"huevos", @"bacon", @"french toast", @"frittata", @"hash brown", @"muesli", @"quiche"],
                  @[@"omelet", @"brunch", @"pancake", @"waffle", @"huevos", @"bacon", @"blintz", @"sausage", @"casserole", @"crepe", @"egg", @"french toast", @"bacon", @"french toast", @"frittata", @"hash brown", @"muesli", @"quiche", @"salad", @"salmmon", @"soup", @"tartine"],
                  @[@"dessert", @"sweet", @"waffle", @"cake"],
                  @[@"appetizer", @"soup", @"side", @"fruit", @"starter", @"snack", @"bread", @"spread"],
                  @[@"coffee", @"drink", @"beverage", @"espresso", @"cappuccino", @"americano", @"latte", @"macchiato", @"frappuccino", @"flat white"]
                  ];
```

Now when I search against a given sentence, I want to match any string in that array against any word in the sentence, that matches left hand side.
So if I have a sentence like "Hot bagels with cheese", it should match the string "bagel" contained in the second array.

My approach is this one:

```
NSString *dishName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\w*",@"sentence goes here"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF IN %@", dishName];
NSArray *matchedArray = [menuItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if (matchedArray.count>0) {
    NSLog(@"found match for dish name:%@",@"sentence");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Didn't match dish name:%@",@"sentence");
}
```

Now comes the weirdness.
According to the regular expression I'm matching on the left a word boundary, so it shouldn't do wildcard matching from the left side.

**However when my sentence is for example: @"Grilled Tuna Steak Burrito (1 Piece)"
It matches the "tea" string in the first array for the word "Steak".**

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919934/nspredicate-for-exact-match

Comment: I didn't want to use a block predicate for that. Anyway, found my mistake, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok stupid of me, I was using the "IN" comparison instead of "MATCHES" (forgot it from a previous iteration of the code).

Changing the IN to MATCHES solved it

**Update**

No it didn't quite solve it as it wouldn't match words in the sentence.
Needed to change the regex to:

```
NSString *dishName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\w*",[@"some sentence here" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"|"]];
```

Now it is working as expected