# NSPredicate search comma separated value with array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nspredicate, nscompoundpredicate

Have a entity filed called `"keyword"` which containing comma separated value like `"8275,8276,8277"`. Now using NSPredicate search those users whose keyword matching on this and the passing value is an NSArray. Trying to fetch using `(keywords contains[cd] %@)` which is working single value, not working for an array.

The predicate is like that,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((eventId == %@) AND (keywords contains[cd] %@) AND (attendeeIsVisible == %@))",self.appDelegate.currentEvent.entityId,selectedTagID,[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]
```

After printing the predicate it's like -

```
eventId == 18230 AND keywords CONTAINS[cd] {"8275", "8276", "8277"} AND attendeeIsVisible == 1
```

Trying the compound Predicate also like

```
NSMutableArray *parr = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id locaArrayObject in selectedTagID) {
   [parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keywords contains[cd] %@ ",locaArrayObject]];
}

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((eventId == %@) AND (keywords contains[cd] %@) AND (attendeeIsVisible == %@))",self.appDelegate.currentEvent.entityId,selectedTagID,[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

NSPredicate *predicateObj = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate, parr]];
```

Not working also. Any idea where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919934/nspredicate-for-exact-match

Comment: Have checked that but unable to get the logic how it will work for "fetchRequest"

Comment: @SantanuDasAdhikary Check my answer once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `keywords contains[cd] %@` from your `predicate` then `CompoundPredicate` works for you.

```
NSMutableArray *parr = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id locaArrayObject in selectedTagID) {
    [parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keywords contains[cd] %@ ",locaArrayObject]];
}

NSPredicate *eventPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((eventId == %@) AND (attendeeIsVisible == %@))",self.appDelegate.currentEvent.entityId,[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

NSPredicate *keywordPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates: parr];

//Now use below predicate with your array
predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [eventPredicate, keywordPredicate]];
```

Comment: @SantanuDasAdhikary Welcome mate :)